# Are both the given sentences grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

> I needed help. And who better to help me out than him? The guy who'd helped me several times before.

> I needed help. And who better to help me out than him, the guy who'd helped me several times before?

Are both these sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, they are both grammatically OK. A slight improvement: avoid the phrasal verb 'help ... out' since you have simply used 'help' afterwards.

Comment: Neither are ok. If possible, you should not start sentences with a conjunction.

Comment: @FeliniusRex That's a style choice, not a rule of grammar, and as far as I know, it only applies to "and", not all conjunctions.

Comment: This question, as it stands, is a request for proof-reading, and therefore off-topic for this site. You could improve the question by editing it (using the small "Edit" button under the text) to make it clearly about one specific point of grammar that you're uncertain about. Are you asking about starting a sentence with "and"? Are you asking whether the last sentence is correct? Maybe you already know that a sentence requires a conjugated verb, and are asking if in this context the last sentence might be acceptable based on something else you've seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

English grammarians strongly discourage beginning new sentences with a conjunction like "and."  Everyone learns this in English class in the US.  This rule is often ignored in very informal writing, such as in cartoons, phone text, or internet chats, but not often otherwise.  In actuality, the rule is not really so absolute, and it is thought among some advanced, academic, or professional writers that occasionally beginning sentences with conjunctions is good style in appropriate contexts, despite what the supposed "grammarians" say.

Even assuming your sentences are for a context that would permit using "And" at the beginning of a sentence, the first option is still not permitted writing style.  The last "sentence" does not have a finite verb (explicit or understood) or any other type of assertion in it and so cannot be used as an independent sentence.  The second "sentence" is also suspect, since it does not contain a finite verb; however, I think it is one of those unusual sentences in English that does make an assertion without using one and so arguably can stand by itself.

Normally, I think the thought expressed in your sentences would be written:

> I needed help, and who better to help me out than him, the guy who'd
> helped me several times before.

The second comma is required because the material after it is in apposition with the pronoun "him," but is not a part of the sentence required to keep the same overall meaning.

An advanced or bold writer, such as novelist, might replace the first comma with a dash or a colon, which would better express the oral pause that would be necessary in this case.  In that case, it would be:

> I needed help--and who better to help me out than him, the guy who'd
> helped me several times before.

Comment: "And" is even used to start a sentence in academic writing. Your information is outdated.

Comment: Sorry, I would have subsumed "academic writers" under the phrase "professional writers," but can correct it if you find it misleading.  I could probably add "technical writers/writing" as well, but then should also qualify the statement and say "some professional writers" etc.  I'm not sure what we would find if we looked through the opinion page of the New York Times even over a week's worth of writing.

Comment: I don't think technical writers (manuals and instructions) would use it. It is used in writing that presents intellectual arguments or in literary writing.

Comment: I went ahead and edited my answer to be more complete and accurate.  I think the term "advanced writers" should cover anybody I left out.  I was trying to balance what to say for a non-native speaker unacquainted with our fights over long-standing rules that some people break (e.g., "To split or not to split an infinitive").

Comment: Technical writers do not do it.

Answer (score -1):

Both are incorrect lol.

I think you mean something similar to:

> I needed help. And who could help me out better than him the guy who helped me several times before?

Comment: _Who better to [verb] than him?_ is a perfectly normal expression in English.

Comment: @KateBunting Really? Then my English sucks i guess. XD

Comment: You just happen not to be familiar with this particular idiom. Compare [this](https://ludwig.guru/s/who+better+to+ask+than)